# Відмінок після "згідно"

Tags: відмінювання

> Вартість *згідно* **вашого** **тарифного** **плану**.

Я дуже часто чую або бачу такі повідомлення. Але мені здається, що правильно казати `згідно (кому? чому?) вашому тарифному плану`. Чи це не так?

Comment: Взагалі-то правильно [«згідно з _чимось_»](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=35263&page=1119). Але канцеляризм і калька з російської «згідно _чому_» настільки часто зараз уживається, що я й не знаю, як це сприймати. А «згідно _чого_» — це калька з російської часів XIX ст., причому вже тоді це сприймалася як канцеляризм навіть у самій російській.

Comment: Схоже на *згідно з* тільки без *з*, тоді дійсно [має бути орудний](http://www.mova.info/article.aspx?l1=114&DID=340).

Comment: @Yola, без «з» ніяк не може бути орудний.

Comment: Чи не дублікат до [«Згідно з чим „згідно чому“ є неправильним узгодженням іменника з прийменником?»](/q/1508)?